# Random Forest discrepancy between R and Matlab & Python

Tags: python, r, matlab, machine-learning, random-forest

I apply the random forest algorithm in three different programming languages to the same pseudo sample dataset (1000 obs, binary 1/0 dependent variable, 10 numeric explanatory variables):

1. **Matlab** 2015a (same for 2012a) using the **"Treebagger"** command (part of the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox)
2. **R** using the **"randomForest"** package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/index.html
3. **Python** using the **"RandomForestClassifier"** from sklearn.ensemble: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html

I also try to to keep all model parameters identical across programming languages (no. of trees, bootstrap sampling of the whole sample, no. of variables randomly sampled as candidates at each split, criterion to measure the quality of a split).

While Matlab and Python produce basically the same results (i.e. probabilties), the R results are very different.

**What could be the possible reason for the difference between the results produced by R on the one hand side, and by Matlab & Python on the other?**

I guess there's some default model parameter that differs in R which I'm not aware of or which is hard-coded in the underlying randomForest package.

The exact code I ran looks as follows:

**Matlab:**

```
 b = TreeBagger(1000,X,Y, 'FBoot',1, 'NVarToSample',4, 'MinLeaf',1, 'Method', 'classification','Splitcriterion', 'gdi')
 [~,scores,~] = predict(b,X);
```

**Python:**

```
 clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, max_features=4, bootstrap=True)
 scores_fit = clf.fit(X, Y)
 scores = pd.DataFrame(clf.predict_proba(X))
```

**R:**

```
 results.rf <- randomForest(X,Y,  ntree=1000, type = "classification", sampsize = length(Y),replace=TRUE,mtry=4)
 scores <- predict(results.rf, type="prob",
    norm.votes=FALSE, predict.all=FALSE, proximity=FALSE, nodes=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `predict` on a `randomForest` object in `R` without providing a dataset, it returns the out-of-bag predictions. In your other methods, you are passing in the training data again. I suspect that if you do this in the R version, your probabilities will be similar:

```
 scores <- predict(results.rf, X, type="prob",
    norm.votes=FALSE, predict.all=FALSE, proximity=FALSE, nodes=FALSE)
```

Also note, that if you want unbiased probabilites, the R approach of returning OOB predictions is the best approach when predicting on training data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I implemented your suggested solution and the results improved significantly.

Comment: To be precise: All three software packages yield basically identical results. Anyway, I have a quick follow-up question: Can anyone explain the huge difference in computation time between R & Python on the one hand, where results are obtained instantaneously, and Matlab on the other hand, where the model estimation and prediction take several seconds each?

Comment: The R implementation is written in Fortran. The scikit version is Cython, I believe. I suspect the Matlab version is pure Matlab?

Comment: @Zelazny7 - The R implementation is in fact written in C (source: https://github.com/cran/randomForest/tree/master/src), although it is based on Breiman/Cutler's original Fortran code